Weibull Three Parameters Estimation using Maximum Likelihood and optimization methods
I'm having a problem estimating the Weibull three parameters using ML and optimization methods. My results in some of the methods do not look right. However, when a plot the curve looks fine with the histogram of the dimeters.
I'm using this code based on diameters:
diameters <-c(8.9,  8.8,  7.9,  8.0,  8.6,  7.0,  8.6,  8.4,  7.9,  9.3,  7.4,  8.0,  6.2,  8.4,  6.8,  8.7,  8.5,  8.1,  7.6,  7.1, 4.9,  8.4,  7.0,  7.2,  9.0,  4.2, 10.0,  7.7,  8.7,  9.2,  8.9,  8.8,  8.0,  6.6,  8.8,  6.5,  8.7,  8.3)


 dweibull3 <- function(x,gamma, beta, alpha){
 (gamma/beta)* ((x-alpha)/beta)^(gamma-1)*(exp(-((x-alpha)/beta)^gamma))

}

 ll.w3 <- function(p,data) sum(log(dweibull3(data, p[1],p[2],p[3])))

To estimate the parameters my initial values are from the result of Weibull 2 parameters, to estimate the Weibull 2 parameters I used the same diameters data. The alpha, in the diameters distribution, can be the minimum diameter or 0, in this case, I put 0.
  mle.w3 <- optimx(c(gamma=9.019326, beta=8.381865, alpha=0),
             ll.w3,
             method=c("BFGS","Nelder-Mead","CG","nlm","nlminb","spg","ucminf","bobyqa"),
             data =diameters,
             hessian = TRUE,
             control = list(fnscale=-1,
                            maxit=100))

mle.w3

             gamma       beta       alpha          value       fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1
BFGS         24.883809  22.391498 -13.9742073  -5.553528e+01    144    100    NA        1  TRUE
Nelder-Mead 118.034931 103.915303 -95.4904567  -5.542061e+01    102     NA    NA        1 FALSE
CG            9.199371   8.624956  -0.2431863  -5.621682e+01    302    101    NA        1 FALSE
 nlm                 NA         NA          NA  8.988466e+307     NA     NA    NA     9999    NA
nlminb        9.866342  11.052078   4.2000000  -6.645202e+02     96    212    48        1    NA
spg                 NA         NA          NA  8.988466e+307     NA     NA    NA     9999    NA
ucminf              NA         NA          NA  8.988466e+307     NA     NA    NA     9999    NA
bobyqa        9.096683  10.128650   3.3578599  -2.654017e+02     27     NA    NA        0 FALSE

Based on the results the best the BFGS and Nelder-Mead is very weird numbers, but when I plot them they are very close each other and also close with the curve of Weibull 2 parameters. the bobyqa looks the best on, because the convcode equal to 0. Many sources says that BFGS and Nelder Mead are the best option for estimate parameters using optimization. However, does not look right  in my case. Can anyone help me? Is it a problem with my data, my code, my initial values?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817883/fitting-a-3-parameter-weibull-distribution

if the convergence code is 1 you should always adjust the run so that it allows more iterations. Looking at the fitted curves, bobyqa and nlminb are giving bogus answers (seem to be getting stuck near the starting values).

Hi Ben, Thanks for your answer. What do you mean "adjust the run so that it allows more iterations"? how would you do that?

use control = list(fnscale=-1,  maxit=10000))

This isn't a complete answer (in particular, it doesn't explain what this weird corner of parameter space means), but:

whenever conv is 1 that means the run isn't finished (max iterations reached), so you should let the optimizers run longer: in the example below I ran optimx setting the maxit control value to 10000 rather than 100.


There's overly complicated code below showing how I set up this picture.
The conclusion from looking at the picture is that nlminb and bobyqa are giving bogus answers (getting stuck somewhere near the starting values). Even allowing 10,000 iterations, CG still didn't finish (which probably explains why it doesn't quite match BFGS and Nelder-Mead).
As to why this is bad/hard:

very large values of gamma concentrate the distribution at a spike
by adjusting the threshold and the scale, you can counterbalance the effects of gamma by shifting and broadening the peak (in the two-parameter Weibull, the peak is exactly at beta, so you don't have the flexibility to broaden the peak (by increasing beta) while changing its position at the same time (changing alpha) ...

library(optimx)

## a slightly more stable version of dweibull3
dweibull3 <- function(x, gamma, beta, alpha, log = FALSE) {
    lf <- log(gamma)-log(beta) +
        (gamma-1)*log((x-alpha)/beta) +
        -((x-alpha)/beta)^gamma
    if (log) lf else exp(lf)
}

mle.w3 <- optimx(c(gamma=9.019326, beta=8.381865, alpha=0),
             ll.w3,
             method=c("BFGS","Nelder-Mead","CG","nlm","nlminb","spg","ucminf","bobyqa"),
             data =diameters,
             hessian = TRUE,
             control = list(fnscale=-1,
                            maxit=10000))

mle.w3

par(las = 1)
cols <- c()
hist(diameters, freq  = FALSE, breaks = 20)
models <- unlist(attr(mle.w3, "details")[1:8])
j <- 0
pp <- palette.colors()[-c(1,5)] ## skip black and yellow
for (i in 1:length(mle.w3$gamma)) {
    if (is.na(mle.w3$gamma[i])) next
    j <- j + 1
    cols[j] <- pp[j]
    names(cols)[j] <- models[i]
    curve(dweibull3(x, gamma = mle.w3$gamma[i],
                    beta = mle.w3$beta[i],
                    alpha = mle.w3$alpha[i]),
          add = TRUE,
          lwd = 2,
          col = cols[j])
}
legend("topleft", col = cols, lty = 1, legend = names(cols))


Hello Ben, Thanks for your help and time. I'm not sure I understood what did you said. What would you suggest? Do you think my parameters from "BFGS","Nelder-Mead" is right?
